# Xcode change image on button that is not sender

Tags: xcode, uiimage, ibaction

I am trying to change a image of a button that is not the senders, I have tried to link the code to the buttons and it seems not to work
I tried to link the 3 buttons to the -(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender; it still does not work.

.h

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)ButtonUn1:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)ButtonDef1:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender

{
    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_Not_At_all_R.png"];

    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Unsure.png"];
    UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Definitely.png"];

    [ButtonUn1 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ButoonDef1 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where is the definition of ButtonUn1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an IBOutlet for your button and link it to access it directly:

```
IBOutlet UIButton* buttonToChangePicture;
```

The IBAction ist only used to access an event.

Edit:

Another option is to use viewWithTag.

```
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)[myView viewWithTag:555]
```

You need to set a unique tag for your button first (555 in my example)
There is no other way to access another button in an IBAction

Comment: So there is no way to access the other buttons inside the IBAction?

Comment: I am getting an error on myView part:-(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender
{
UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_Not_At_all_R.png"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Unsure.png"];
    UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Definitely.png"];
    UIButton* ButtonUn1 = (UIButton*)[myView viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton* ButtonDef1 = (UIButton*)[myView viewWithTag:2];
    [ButtonUn1 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ButtonDef1 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

Comment: What does the error say? Did you set the right tag for the button? Do you have an IBOutlet to your 'myView' or is it part of your ViewController?

Comment: myView was just an example in my post. Does your view is really called myView?

Comment: unknown receiver "myView" did you mean 'UIView', sorry I am new to xcode and not sure where to add the view name.

Comment: this is part of the viewController

Comment: No problem. I have no access to XCode right now, so I have to do it out of my memory;). If it's your ViewControllers view and you have set eveything correctly you can do something like UIButton* button = (UIButton*)[self->view viewWithTag:1];